# How safe is it to use Truffle and store a seed in a script?

Tags: truffle

I want to do a script to automate an action. The script would run locally on my computer, using Truffle/HD-wallet-provider.

Is it safe? Having my seed in the first line of the script, or do I have to take special security measures?  This is my first time trying this.

Also, is it safe to host such a script on Amazon AWS? Would I need to change it?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: It is an issue on the server side issue and it isn't related to Ethereum. See this for an expert recomendation https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180243/best-practices-for-storing-credentials-used-by-code.